# give access to just one page for blocked ips in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a site in development, I want only my IP to access the website and block all other IPs. I could do that with `allow 1.2.3.4` in `Nginx` and `deny all`. However I want other visitors to see just one page `index.html` which says:

> Welcome to The site, Stay Tuned

how to make only one page accessible for global users like that in Nginx ?

I tried with `error_page` like

```
location / {
allow 1.2.3.4;
deny all;
error_page 403 index.html;
}
```

but this creates redirects and I get `the website has too many redirects` while accessing from other ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow access to the error page in a matching `location`.

```
location = /error403.html {
    allow all;
}

location / {
    ....
    error_page 403 /error403.html;
}
```

Comment: thanks for prompt response... this is what i was looking for